# Comparar listas que sejam exatamente iguais

Tags: c#, .net, lista, linq

Estou tentando implementar um método de comparação de listas que verifica se elas são iguais.

Ele deve retornar verdadeiro quando as duas listas passadas por parâmetro são exatamente iguais (numero de elementos, elementos e ordenação).

Eu consegui desenvolver parte da solução:

```
public bool ListasIguais(ICollection<string> x, ICollection<string> y)
{
     if (x.Count != y.Count)
         return false;


     return x.Except(y).Count() == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Porém ele não está considerando a ordem dos elementos, ou seja, `{"a", "b", "c"}` e `{"c", "b", "a"}` ele considera como iguais.

Como faço para ele considerar a ordenação? Também queria que ele pudesse receber outros tipos de coleções e não apenas strings, ou seja, que ele aceite `ICollection<int>`, `ICollection<double>`, `ICollection<string>`, `ICollection<byte>`. Caso contrario eu teria que sobrecarregar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SequenceEqual()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do Linq para fazer da forma mais "enxuta" possível:

```
public bool ListasIguais(ICollection<string> x, ICollection<string> y) => x.SequenceEqual(y);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/CompareLists.cs).

Inclusive acho estranho o uso de `ICollection<string>`, pode até ter motivo, mas parece mais que é algo usado sem motivo e um limitador desnecessário. na verdade é tão simples que nem tem porque criar um método só para isto.

Mesmo que fosse usar o código da pergunta não faz sentido usar um `if` ou operador ternário para gerar `true` ou `false`, é justamente isso que eles fazem.